# Last inserted id

Tags: php

This is my query

```
$vipinsert = "INSERT INTO `$amxadmins` (`id`, `password`, `access` , `flags` ,`steamid` , `ashow` , `created` , `expired` , `days`) VALUES ('', '$logged[password]', '$accessvip', '$flagsvip' , '$logged[username]' , '$ashowvip' , '$createdvip' , '$expiredvip' , '$daysvip')";
    mysql_query($vipinsert) or die(mysql_error());
    $vipselect = mysql_query("SELECT * from `$amxadmins` WHERE steamid = '$logged[username]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $custom1 = '';
    $static1 = 'no';
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($vipselect);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$admins_servers` (`admin_id`, `server_id`, `custom_flags`, `use_static_bantime`) VALUES ('$row[id]', '$server', '$custom1', '$static1')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Is there anyway to select the id from this

```
$vipinsert = "INSERT INTO `$amxadmins` (`id`, `password`, `access` , `flags` ,`steamid` , `ashow` , `created` , `expired` , `days`) VALUES ('', '$logged[password]', '$accessvip', '$flagsvip' , '$logged[username]' , '$ashowvip' , '$createdvip' , '$expiredvip' , '$daysvip')";
```

Excuse my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 6):

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

will return the value of the primary key of the last inserted row.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to discover `mysql_insert_id()`